# Clojure: What regular expression can I use to detect the last character of a line in a multi-line string?

Tags: java, regex, clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to match the last character at the end of each line (multi-line text string) in Clojure. Here is a sample text:

```
"Possible values:

copy: A copy of the source item is made at the new location.
move: An item is moved to a new location.
link: A link is established to the source at the new location.
none: The item may not be dropped."
```

I tried `#"\n"` but that only matches a new line.

Comment: `(?m).$`? ...........

Comment: I just tried #".$" and it did not work. I found it works for Ruby though. Would you know how to do it for Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#"\n|$"`; `\n` to match all newlines except the last one, and `$` to match the last one.

```
user=> (print (clojure.string/replace text #"\n|$" "...\n"))
Possible values:...
...
copy: A copy of the source item is made at the new location....
move: An item is moved to a new location....
link: A link is established to the source at the new location....
none: The item may not be dropped....
```

Comment: Where could I find resources online for Clojure regexes? I tried Googling before asking on Stackoverflow, but came up with nothing.

Comment: clojure regex is java regex. So java regex should suffice